# boost::bind placeholder issue when binding Handler to a boost::asio::strand

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-bind

```
void Connection::HandleRecvData(const boost::system::error_code & error)
{
    boost::asio::async_read( m_socket, boost::asio::buffer( m_recv_buffer ),
           m_io_strand.wrap( boost::bind( &Connection::HandleRecvData,
                                          shared_from_this(), _1, _2 ) ) ); //works
    boost::asio::async_read( m_socket, boost::asio::buffer( inbound_data_ ),
           m_io_strand.wrap( boost::bind( &Connection::HandleRecv, 
                                          shared_from_this(), _1, _2 ) ) ); //doesn't work
}
```

Handler

```
void Connection::HandleRecv( const boost::system::error_code & error, int32_t actual_bytes )
{
    if( error || HasError() || m_hive->HasStopped() )
    {
        StartError( error );
    }
    else
    {
        m_recv_buffer.resize( actual_bytes );
        OnRecv( m_recv_buffer );
        m_pending_recvs.pop_front();
        if( !m_pending_recvs.empty() )
        {
            StartRecv( m_pending_recvs.front() );
        }
    }
}
```

Different buffer types:

```
std::vector< uint8_t > m_recv_buffer;  //and 
std::vector< char > m_recv_buffer;
```

I am not getting a compiler error but at runtime when the chain of events to recieve the data is kicked off the "&Connection::HandleRecv" is never called. I am assuming that it is because the function signature is incorrect when the placeholders are evaluated and the function is never called.

Can anyone help explain how the placeholders are evaluated/sub'd in.

I have checked the bind documentation and I see:

```
bind(&X::f, ref(x), _1)(i);     // x.f(i)
bind(&X::f, &x, _1)(i);         //(&x)->f(i)
bind(&X::f, x, _1)(i);          // (internal copy of x).f(i)
bind(&X::f, p, _1)(i);          // (internal copy of p)->f(i)
```

but there is no "(i)" when I am calling it.

```
boost::bind( &Connection::HandleRecvData, shared_from_this(), _1, _2 )
```

PS this is my first post any tips would be helpful as far as the level of detail I've provided and where I can be more clear in describing my issue next time. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the shown code of `Connection::HandleRecvData`the _real_ code ? If so, it's plain wrong. You (1) create an infinite loop, and (2) it's not allowed to call `async_read` while another call is pending.

Comment: No it should be `&Connection::HandleRecv`. In any case only one of those two calls will exist. I put both there to show one that was working and one that was not working.